# Некорректный вывод данных в форме select через Hibernate

Tags: javascript, java, spring, hibernate

Пишу проект на java/spring/hibernate и немного js.

Когда я добавляю в форму select инфо из mySQL, то поля select-a множатся.

Мне нужно, чтобы они шли снизу вверх по форме, а таких полей становится три.

```html
   <tr>

        <td style="font-size: large;">Выбрать семестр</td>

        <td style="padding-left: 50px">

            <c:forEach items="${semestrs}" var="sem">
            <select name="selected"
                    id="opening_list">

                        <option value="${sem.id}">${sem.name}</option>

<%--                            <option value="${sem.id}">${sem.name} </option>--%>

            </select>


            </c:forEach>

        </td>


        <td style="padding-left: 20px"><input type="submit"
                                              value="Выбрать" id="button"></td>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы итерируете селекты - они и множаться.

Итерируйте option и все будет нормально

Просто переместите `<c:forEach>` внутрь селекта

```html
<tr>
    <td style="font-size: large;">Выбрать семестр</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 50px">
        <%-- отсюда c:forEach  убераем --%>
        <select name="selected" id="opening_list">
            <%-- перемещаем его внутрь селекта --%>
            <c:forEach items="${semestrs}" var="sem">
                <option value="${sem.id}">${sem.name}</option>
                <%--<option value="${sem.id}">${sem.name} </option>--%>
            </c:forEach>        
        </select>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left: 20px">
        <input type="submit" value="Выбрать" id="button">
    </td>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , помогло !

Comment: @MarkKush, не за что. Задавайте вопросы еще. Надеюсь, поможем)